# php json response in ajax call

Tags: php, json

here is my php code

```
function GetTransactionList($data)
{
    // DB transaction   
    $records = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        array_push($records, $row);

    echo json_encode(array("IsError" => false, "Records" => $records));
```

}

this is my json response in ajax call from php

```
{
    IsError:false,
    Records:[
            {0:1,
             1:1000,
             2:0,
             3:"Peacock India trial payment",
             4:"2013-08-03",
             5:1,
             TransactionID:1,
             Credit:1000,
             Debit:0,
             Reason:"Peacock India trial payment",
             TransactionDate:"2013-08-03",
             TransactionByUserID:1
            }]
}
```

here I got my result but json_encode() method encodes each row twice first it sets values by index=>value pair and second time it encodes by column_name=>value pair. I want to know why it happens? Is there any way to reduce this double work.? I want json response only as following way

```
{
    IsError:false,
    Records:[
            {TransactionID:1,
             Credit:1000,
             Debit:0,
             Reason:"Peacock India trial payment",
             TransactionDate:"2013-08-03",
             TransactionByUserID:1
            }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't, it is `mysql_fetch_array` that gives you both associate and numeric keys.
If you only want associative keys specify it in the function `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);`

Comment: Just an FYI, the options are **MYSQL_ASSOC**, **MYSQL_NUM**, and **MYSQL_BOTH** according to the [mySQL mysql_fetch_array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`.